# Python: Is there a way to generate xsd files based on xml examples

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I have a list of xml examples I would like to turn into schemas (xsd files). Exactly what the trang tool does (http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). I don't like calling trang from my script (i.e doing `os.system('java -jar trang...')`) - is there a python package I can use instead?

Comment: I do not think it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jython (http://jython.org/) then you could import trang and run it internally.